# Find the value of the summation of 3 to the power of n

Tags: summation

I'm suppose to find the value of

$$
\sum\limits_{i=5}^{100}(3)^n
$$

My professor gave me the first step to this which is 
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}(3)^n - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{4}(3)^n
$$

and I honestly can't figure out what to do next. I did not find this question posted anywhere else so if it is sorry for posting and can you redirect me?

Comment: I guess that your professsor, apart from giving you the first step must have also given you some formula for the summation of geometric series. Have you studied it before asking?

Comment: Hint: when $a\neq1$, $\sum_{k=0}^na^k=1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^n=\dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$.

Comment: Besides the professor's hint, another approach would be to factor $3^5$ out of the sum (and then apply the geometric series formula you were presumably given).

Comment: the summation formulas that he gave to us does not cover anything to the power of n or anything similar to what I have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}3^n=\sum_{i=1}^4 3^n+\sum_{i=5}^{100} 3^n$$
$$3\frac{1-3^{100}}{1-3}=3+3^2+3^3+3^4 +\sum_{i=5}^{100} 3^n$$
$$\frac{3^{101}-3}{2}-120=\sum_{i=5}^{100} 3^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint. Let $1+r+r^2+...+r^n = x$ and we want to find $x$. Then we see:

$$1+r+r^2+...+r^n = x$$
$$(1+r+r^2+...+r^n)(1-r) = x(1-r)$$
$$(1+r+r^2+...+r^n)-(r+r^2+...+r^n+r^{n+1})=x(1-r)$$
$$1-r^{n+1} = x(1-r)$$
$$\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r} = x$$
$$1+r+r^2+...+r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Can you figure out what $r$ and $n$ are in your problem? (Note that the formula above only works for $r\ne 1$).

Comment: so r = 3 and n = 100 correct?

Comment: Yep - for your first sum (from i=0 to i=100). In your second sum (i=0 to i=4), n=4. It should be noted that since the formula includes r^0, and your summation doesn't (you start with 3+9+... instead of 1+3+9+...), you'd also have to subtract 1 from the formula.